# Perl converting binary stream to hex

Tags: perl, hex, stdin

The problem I am having is when I have a Perl script reading data (PE Executable) via STDIN and the stream contains a line terminator "0A" the conversion to hex misses it. Then when I convert the hex data back it is corrupted (missing 0A in the hex format). So how can I detect the "windows" version of line feed "0A" in Perl?

Note: Linux OS (Perl) is reading a Windows PE

```
!usr/bin/perl

while($line = <STDIN>)
{
    chomp($line);
    @bytes = split //, $line;
    foreach (@bytes)
    {
        printf "%02lx", ord $_;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
[root@mybox test]# cat test.exe | perl encoder.pl > output
```

Answer (score 6):

In your loop, you are running `chomp` on each input line.  This is removing whatever value is currently in `$/` from the end of your line.  Chances are this is `0x0a`, and that's where the value is going.  Try removing `chomp($line)` from your loop.

In general, using line oriented reading doesn't make sense for binary files that are themselves not line oriented.  You should take a look at the lower level `read` function which allows you to read a block of bytes from the file without caring what those bytes are.  You can then process your data in blocks instead of lines.

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing.  I dove straight into messing with `binmode()` and didn't even see the `chomp`.

Comment: Also, you'll find `unpack('H*', $binary_string)` is _much_ more efficient than `split` and `printf '%02x'`.

Comment: made a change#!/usr/bin/perl

binmode(STDIN);
while(<STDIN>)
{
 #print $_;
 push(@bytes,$_);
}
foreach (@bytes)
{
  printf "%02lx", ord $_;
}

Comment: With the code change to binmod + removing chomp the stream is breaking

Comment: Verified chomp is removing the 0a from the encoding stream however I need to insert the following charachters '\x' per hex set eg 0d0d0a24 would be \x0d\x0d\x0a\x24 any suggestions how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: @ekronnenburg => there are several ways to do this, what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
#With split
cat magic.exe | perl -e 'print join("", map { sprintf("\\x%02x", ord($_)) } split(//, join("", <STDIN>)))' > hex_encoded_binary

#With pack
cat magic.exe| perl -e 'print join("", map { "\\x" . $_ } unpack("H*", join("", <STDIN>)) =~ /.{2}/gs)' > hex_encoded_binary
```